# Changing the type of brackets

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I have a document containing these types of strings:

```
C(A,B)

C(D,E)

C(D,
E)
```

I am trying to replace every occurence of `C(...)` with `\SC{...}`, changing the `C` in front of the bracket and the brackets themselves. The brackets can span multiple lines. How can this be done?

Edit: The document contained other types of brackets as well. They should not be replaced.

My idea would be to iterate through occurences, and use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405072/quickest-way-to-change-a-pair-of-parenthesis-to-brackets-in-vim) to replace the brackets.

Comment: Do you have any parenthesis that should *not* be changed to brackets? Then you could simply do several simple substitute commands.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I do have brackets that I do not want to change.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Can you have embedded parenthesis like: `C(A(f), Z())`? Is no, a simple `:substitute` can do it thanks to `\_.\{-}` that'll match as few things as possible on multiple lines. Otherwise, you'll need to search for `C(` and apply the old trick with `%` and `````

Comment: @romainl See the updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the wording of your question, it seems like I can assume that `A`, `B`, `D`, and `E` are not expressions that themselves contain parantheses. Based on the comments, it might not be assumed. I therefore provide two answer.

---

If there are not nested parantheses, then the following regular expression should work:

```
:%s/C(\(\_[^)]\+\))/\\SC{\1}/g
```

Here `\_` allows the following atom to match across line boundaries, see `:h \_`.

---

If there are nested parantheses, the substitution becomes very hard to do with a regular expression (at least in general). In this case, I would rather use a macro:

1. Put the cursor on a `C`, then start recording with `qa`.
2. Do: `s\SC<esc>` to replace `C` with `\SC`.
3. Do: `l%r}` to replace the last `)` with `}`.
4. Do: `<c-o>r{` to replace the first `(` with `{`.
5. Search for next occurance: `/C(`
6. Stop recording: `q`.

Now you may repeat the substitution with `@a` and then `@@` for the consecutive occurances.

Note: Here `<esc>` is the literal escape character and `<c-o>` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>.